# Change UINavigationBar's background image dynamically (Pre-iOS5)

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to create a view that dynamically colors the UINavigationBar based on a property of the class, but I'm having trouble doing so. Any ideas as to how I should do this?

The main problem I'm having is that I have other classes that import this particular class that I'm trying to do this in, and what ends up happening is that those views also get this dynamic navbar.

Is this even possible? Pre-iOS5 only please.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myToolbar insertSubview:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar_40.png"]] autorelease] atIndex:0];
```